# Separating specific data from a file

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to read text from a file and put the stock number and size number into separate strings, then disregard the other information. Below is the text file.

```
stock='2' 

<span class="size">44R</span>
```

I was curious as to how I would get this specific data into a String, I have tried to separate the code with a delimiter but I'm unsure after this.
Below is my code.

```
public void openFile() {
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(new File("testData.txt"));
        scan.useDelimiter("[=><']+");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not find file");
    }
}

public void readFile() {
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.printf(" %s\n", line);// Print out variables
    }
}
```

Comment: is the file written by you in some other program ??

Comment: Have an if statement (using `substring(...)`) to look for 'stock', you can guess the other substring to look for

Comment: Yes Hussain, but thats really irelevant at this stage, im just considering it as a text file.

Comment: Sorry user2860598 i dont follow, can you please give me a little code as an example? Thank you

Comment: If that is HTML or XML, you will need a proper parser: using `Scanner` will not work.

Comment: So what should I do Raedwald?

Comment: Thank you @user2860598 I used substring, but it is no use for me as the length off the text file will change every time I use it, therefore making substring useless.

Comment: @user3008865 Use substring on each line, not the file.

Comment: I am, but what im saying is I would like this bit of code to work on multiple of these files, unfortunately the information i need is never in the same position on its line, although the text immidiately around it is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have no problem in get 2 in `stock='2'` line.

So suppose you have problem to get the value between the html tags (i.e. 44R), the following regular expression filter can work for you:

```
public static String filterHTMLTag( String htmlLine )
{

    htmlLine = Pattern.compile("</?[aA-zZ][aA-zZ0-9]*[^<>]*>").matcher( htmlLine ).replaceAll( "" );
    return htmlLine;
}
```

You add this API and just scan one line, filter the string and get what you want from this file.

Comment: I dont really need that, using back slash before a " makes it normal text anyway.

Comment: You don't need that, so I got confused with your problem somehow. What's your need??